# Examples of functions which are bell-shaped?

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics, graphing-functions

I have been grouping functions based on how their graph looks like. I started with bell-shaped curves and have come up with the following functions:

- cos, sin
- sech (from -1 to 1)
- Infinitely Smooth Radial Basis Functions (RBFs)
- Bump functions (to a certain extent)
- Polynomials (few cases)

What more I can add to this list? I am unable to come up with something new.

Note: The functions should be simple and do not involve piecewise definitions (like Irwin-Hall distribution) or repetitive operations (summations/series/integrals etc.).

Comment: Maybe also 1/(1+x^2)

Comment: $\pi - ( \arctan(x))^2$

Comment: $e^{-x^2}$ is quite popular.

Comment: Generalizing, $e^{-f(x)^2},\frac1{f(x)^2+1}$ where $f(x)\sim x$ and has end behavior like $y=x$ gives a bell shape like [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/r1yhzg16as)

Comment: @ТymaGaidash. Somehow most of the bell curved functions listed fall under this kind of classification. That's interesting. May I ask how you came up with that? Or is it from a textbook or a mathematical subject topic?

Comment: @AravindaVarma We see $e^{-\color{blue}x^2}$ has $x$, so a function $f(x)$ instead of $x$ with a similarly behaved graph like $y=x$ should look bell shaped too.